# Нахождение производной на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Как на Python найти производную функции? В какой библиотеке есть необходимые для этого функции?

Comment: [`SumPy`.](http://www.sympy.org/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#derivatives) (от слов Symbolic math и Python):

```
>>> from sympy import diff, symbols, cos, sin
>>> x, y = symbols('x y')
>>> diff(cos(x))
-sin(x)
>>> diff(cos(x) + 1j*sin(y), x)
-sin(x)
>>> diff(cos(x) + 1j*sin(y), y)
1.0*I*cos(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью функции`scipy.misc.derivative` можно найти производную N-й степени функции в точке.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html

Ещё один вариант - `numpy.diff`, но там на вход принимается массив значений и на выход отдаётся другой массив. Полезно для построения графиков.