# Как найти частную производную от функции двух переменных в Python

Tags: python

```
F(x, y) = x^3 + y^3 - 8
```

Требуется найти производную по x средствами Python

Comment: в сроках написания программы

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Нахождение производной на Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/630116/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html):

```
In [101]: from sympy import *

In [102]: x, y = symbols('x y')

In [103]: diff(x**3 + y**3, x)
Out[103]: 3*x**2

In [104]: r = diff(x**3 + y**3, x)

In [105]: r
Out[105]: 3*x**2

In [106]: type(r)
Out[106]: sympy.core.mul.Mul

In [107]: print(r)
3*x**2
```