# Как реализовать символьное дифференцирование на python?

Tags: python, математика, польская-запись

У меня есть задача- реализовать символьное дифференцирование на питоне(именно самому написать),но это у меня не получается. Я смог реализовать только перевод в обратную польскую запись(исходное выражение представляется в виде списка операторов и операнд в ОПЗ),а само взятие производной я не знаю ,как сделать. Можете, пожалуйста, помочь с реализацией функции взятия производной(от суммы/разности, произведения и частного). Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Нахождение производной на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/630116/23044)

Comment: из ОПЗ дифференцировать не получится — так или иначе придётся переводить выражение в древовидную форму — а там уж будет очевидно, как дифференцировать....

Comment: если у вас уже есть база для системы символических вычислений (типа mathematica, maple, sage, maxima, sympy), то самостоятельно несложно дифференцирование реализовать. Иначе вопрос слишком обширный.

Comment: @jfs нет,надо все реализовать самостоятельно(ручками), без использования связанных с этим вопросов модулей

Comment: @Fat-Zer а вроде же ОПЗ представляется как дерево,нет? Если нет ,то как реализовать перевод в дерево и нахождение производной(именно нахождение производное я не знаю ,как реализовать ,нет идеи ,как создать нужную функцию)

Comment: @RGeorgy: я не сказал используйте эти модули. Они упомянуты, для иллюстрации, чтобы было ясно как "база для системы символических вычислений" может выглядеть¶ Если вы с нуля хотите писать, то вопрос слишком обширный. Начните с реализации простейших символических операций +-*/ со скобками. Когда научитесь работать с простейшими арифметическими выражения с константами и переменными, легко будет дифференцирование реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

*Обратная польская запись* представляет собой в первом приближении стек и не особо подходит для дифференцирования. Удобна она в первую очередь для реализации вычислений, когда выражение надо раскручивать снизу. Операция дифференцирования напротив требует раскручивать выражение сверху, поэтому выражение удобней всего будет привести в древовидную форму, где у каждой операции есть свои аргументы. В принципе достаточно будет просто (есть свои подводные камни) развернуть ОПЗ, получив *Префиксную нотацию* и работать уже с ней, но это создаст ряд неудобств.

Сам алгоритм дифференцирования довольно прост, обычная вариативная рекурсия с описанием как дифференцировать различные функции(псевддокод):

```
def diff (f):
  if (f.operation == "+"):
    return functor ("+", diff (f.left), diff (f.right))
  elif (f.operation == "-"):
    return functor ("-", diff (f.left), diff (f.right))
  elif (f.operation == "*"):
    return functor ( "+", functor ( "*", diff (f.left), f.right),
                          functor ( "*", f.left, diff (f.right)))
  # ...
  elif (f.operation == "exp"):
    return functor ("*", functor ("exp", f.subFunc), diff (f.subFunc))
  elif (f.operation == "ln"):
    return functor ("/", diff (f.subFunc), f.subFunc)
  elif (f.operation == "const"):
    return functor ("const", 0)
  elif (f.operation == "x"):
    return functor ("const", 1)
  else:
    raise UnknownOperation
```